# How to make a row of 5 columns in Bootstrap 4 when the columns are being added programmatically

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am having a hard time when displaying products on the home page of a store.

```
   <div class="row">

  @foreach($produts as $product)  //this is the syntax of my templating engine

   <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>


  @endforeach
 </div>
```

When I use col-md-3 (4 products are shown) the products appear too big on the screen and when I use col-md-2 (6 products are shown) the products appear too small. So I want to divide it into 5 columns. It's not a question of being perfectionist, it's very discrepant, this totally breaks the design. I read some question saying to use class="col" but for me it doesn't work because I'm adding several products programmatically. The products split in several "lines".  I really wanted that bootstrap had 24 columns instead of 12. Is there a bootstrap way to accomplish what I want or will I have to fire some pure CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS.

```
.col-20 {-ms-flex: 0 0 20%; flex: 0 0 20%; max-width: 20%;}
@media (min-width: 576px) {.col-sm-20 {-ms-flex: 0 0 20%; flex: 0 0 20%; max-width: 20%;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.col-md-20 {-ms-flex: 0 0 20%; flex: 0 0 20%; max-width: 20%;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.col-lg-20 {-ms-flex: 0 0 20%; flex: 0 0 20%; max-width: 20%;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.col-xl-20 {-ms-flex: 0 0 20%; flex: 0 0 20%; max-width: 20%;}}
```

You can use custom class **col-20** in combination with standard Bootstrap4 cols.

```
<div class="col-xl-20 col-lg-4 col-md-6">...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use an empty div with class col-md-offset-1 to push your product 1 column right and then show the product using col-md-2. It will display 5 products in the middle, not in one side. below is an example . .

```
 <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-offset-1">
<div>

@foreach($produts as $product)  //this is the syntax of my templating engine

<div class="col-md-2">
    $product
</div>


@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add you custom class like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-5th">
    </div>
</div>
```

and add css styles for min-width: 1200px

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-xl-5th {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
}
```